# Can't create/write to file MYSQL в директорию отличную от /var/tmp

Tags: mysql, permissions

*Server version: 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)*

Пытаюсь сохранить вывод в директорию `/var/www/dir/file.csv`

Выдаёт:

> Can't create/write to file '/var/www/dir/file.csv' (Errcode: 13 -
> Permission denied)

Запуск скрипта и запроса идёт через php скрипт в браузере.

Права на папку `/dir/` **ls -al**

`drwxrwxrwx  2 mysql root  4096 Apr 29 10:40 dir`

Answer (score 0):

Это конечно не совсем ответ на вопрос, но:
я проверил, что по умолчанию, mysql разрешено писать в : `/var/lib/mysql-files/`

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`

И переписал пути в php-скрипте на эту директорию.